# Debian 11 - audit logs appearing in /var/log/auth

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I'm on a Debian 11 server and my audit logs are going into /var/log/audit/audit.log as well as in /var/log/auth.log. They are filling up my auth.log and they really should not be going there. Below are the relevant portion of my configs:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
kern.debug                       /var/log/kern.log
daemon.*                         /var/log/daemon.log
*.info;cron,auth,authpriv.none   /var/log/syslog
cron.*                           /var/log/cron.log
user.*                           /var/log/user.log
auth,authpriv.*                  /var/log/auth.log


/etc/audit/auditd.conf
log_file = /var/log/audit.log
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here as to what to do. How do I get my audit logs to send to /var/log/audit/audit.log only?

Answer (score 0):

Audit logs contain information related to authentication and authorization, and therefore, they are sent to the auth facility. This means that by using the following line in your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
auth,authpriv.*                  /var/log/auth.log
```

.. they also end up in `/var/log/auth.log`.

To prevent this from happening, you can redirect the audit logs by appending the following line to your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
audit.*                          /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

This will redirect all logs of the audit facility to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

---

Note that `/var/log/audit/audit.log` is the default log file for the audit daemon. However, it seems like you have edited your `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` to log to `/var/log/audit.log`. I am not sure whether this is intentional or a typo. In any case, you probably want to use two separate log files.